# page attribute in <jsp:include> with @WebServlet and web.xml

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml

Don't comment on the convention used in naming packages in Java.

There is a Servlet inside the package ***Ch7ActionTags*** mapped with

```
@WebServlet("/FlavorListServlet")
```

My jsp page resides in a folder under ***WebContent*** whose path is:

```
/Ch7RequestDispatching/ActionTags/MyPage.jsp
```

The aforementioned servlet is included in this jsp page like this.

```
<jsp:include page="/FlavorListServlet"></jsp:include>
```

When i tried to run this jsp page, the url in the browser reflects as

```
http://localhost:7860/Phil_Hanna/Ch7RequestDispatching/ActionTags/MyPage.jsp
```

and the servlet is successfully included.

I tried to experiment with the  forward slash ***/***

But these didn't work either:

```
<jsp:include page="FlavorListServlet"></jsp:include> 
<jsp:include page="/Ch7RequestDispatching/ActionTags/FlavorListServlet"></jsp:include>
```

Now going through the same process(***replacing the @WebServlet annotation by servlet-mapping in the web.xml file***)

```
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FlavorListServletName</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Ch7ActionTags.FlavorListServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>FlavorListServletName</servlet-name>
     <url-paatern>/Ch7RequestDispatching/ActionTags/FlavorListServlet
     </url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

My jsp page now:

```
<jsp:include page="FlavorListServlet"></jsp:include> <%-- / is absent here --%>
```

With the above mapping, the servlet content is successfully included.

But this doesn't works,

```
<jsp:include page="/FlavorListServlet"></jsp:include>
```

So, the obvious question is why there is a difference of ***/*** when working the 2 possible scenarios:

```
<jsp:include page="/FlavorListServlet"></jsp:include> works with @WebServlet
<jsp:include page="FlavorListServlet"></jsp:include>  works with web.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Without a slash at the beginning, you include a file which is relative to the current JSP page.
- With a slash at the beginning, you include a file which is relative to the web application's context path (URL starts with a slash)

Comment: Sarvard: I upvoted you. But can you elaborate a bit on the 2nd point. The first pt. is clear to me.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari normally, the web application context path is the name of your war file.